# Player animation mismatches its movement input

Tags: unity, animation

I am using the code below to have the character's directional movement match its movement animations but when the player model has a non-zero y-axis rotation, the animations become mismatched.

Code:

```
    moveVector = new Vector3 (movX, 0, movZ).normalized * (movementSpeed * (1 - pInv.totalMass/20)) * (1 + bonusSpeed);

    animBector = pBody.transform.rotation * moveVector;
    moveVector = gameObject.transform.rotation * moveVector;

    pAnim.SetFloat ("moveSpeed", movementSpeed/2);
    pAnim.SetFloat ("Vertical", animBector.normalized.z);
    pAnim.SetFloat ("Horizontal", animBector.normalized.x);
```

Note that pBody is the mesh body of the playerObject and is a child of gameObject. The gameObject does not rotate since this is a top-down project & the `moveVector = gameObject.transform.rotation * moveVector;` part ensures the player moves towards its respective parts of the screen on pressing a directional button.

e.g. 
forward input while facing North will display a forward animation;
forward+right input while facing North East will display a sideways (or strafe) animation, the correct one should be a forward animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `animBector` to be the movement vector, but local to the apparent direction that the player is facing. This would mean that you need to reverse-apply the rotation of `pBody`.

Please try replacing this line:

```
animBector = pBody.transform.rotation * moveVector;
```

with this one:

```
animBector = pBody.transform.InverseTransformDirection(moveVector);
```

---

If the move vector and the player object might be scaled, but you want `Vertical` and `Horizontal` animation parameters to be unscaled, use `InverseTransformVector` instead.

Comment: I used your suggestion but had to swap the `animBector` axes input into the `pAnim` float parameters to get the directional animations to match. Thanks for your answer!